# Execute tests from the app in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

Is there any provision to executes the Unit tests from the App Target with out using `Product -> Test` may be the below way.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {    
//Call Test cases
return true
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe if you tell us why...?

Comment: @abizern I want to lodge the test results when device is not plugged.